# codeigniter login same message of error

Tags: codeigniter-3

im tryiing to create a login system with cide igniter 
here is my controller

```
<?php
class LoginController extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function checkLogin()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login','Login','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|callback_Verification');

        if($this->form_validation->run() ==false)
        {
            $this->load->view('login');

        }
        else
        {
              redirect('HomeController/index');


        }

    }

     public function Verification()
    {
        $login = $this->input->post('login');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->model('LoginModel');
        if($this->LoginModel->Login('$login','$password'))

        {
         return true;
        }

        else

        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('Verification','Mot  de passe ou login incorrect');

            return false;
        }   

    }
```

}

?>
here is the model

```
<?php
class LoginModel extends CI_Model {



        public function Login($login, $password)
        {

                $this->db->select('login','password');
                $this->db->from('users');
                $this->db->where('login',$login);
                $this->db->where('password',$password);

                $query = $this->db->get();
                if($query->num_rows()==1){ 
                        return true;

                }else{ 
                        return false;

                }

        }


}
?>
```

why isnt it workin it gives me the set message (login incorrect wether i enter a correct login or not I cant find the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the issue with Codeigniter 3.0 version, there is a problem with their session handling class.
For now i would suggest using the Codeiginter 2.x version, since the 3.0 versions are still ongoing development.
I ran into this problem earlier and it took days for me to figure out that problem.